# How to control way that <p> tags are wrapping text pasted in source code window

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

How to configure TinyMCE 6 so that when I input this into source code:

```
Above text

<br>

<br>

<img class=" wp-image-277296 alignright" src="my-image.png" alt="" />
<h2>Title</h2>
Some text
```

It gets transformed into this (separate `<p>` or block tags for each line of text, this is what I want):

```
<p>Above text</p>

<br>

<br>

<img class=" wp-image-277296 alignright" src="my-image.png" alt="" />
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
```

Default behaviour is wrapping everything in single `<p>` tag and I want to avoid it:

```
<p>
   Above text

   <br>

   <br>

   <img class=" wp-image-277296 alignright" src="my-image.png" alt="" />
   <h2>Title</h2>
   Some text
</p>
```